# Section not working with CSS Sticky Footer

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I'm trying to get the footer to stay on the bottom of the page, even if the content is too short. I do not want a fixed footer. I want a sticky footer.

I have a section that is causing the issues. I just want the section to fill the space to the footer, and not have a scroll bar unless there is one necessary.

http://fabricatorsunlimited.com/test/quartzcare.html

This is the page I'm working on since there is no content. Are you can see, you have to scroll to view the scroll bar, even though there is no content.

HTML

```
<head>
</HEAD>

<body class="size-960">
<section> 

<!-- HEADER -->
<header>
</header> 

<!-- HOME PAGE BLOCK -->      
<div class="line">
<div class="margin"></div></div>

<!-- ASIDE NAV AND CONTENT -->
<div class="line">
<div class="box margin-bottom">
<div class="margin"> 

<!-- CONTENT --> 
<article class="s-12 l-8">
<h1>Quartz Care</h1>
<p>....</p>

</div></article></div></div>

</section>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    * {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;}

html {height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;}

*,*:before,*:after {box-sizing: inherit;}

body {
font-family: "Open Sans";
color: #413D3D;
background: url("bodyback.png");
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;}

.box {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 1.25em;
margin-top: 20px;
border-top: 1px #0068B3 solid;
background-color:#ffffff;
min-height: 100%;}

section {
min-height: 100%;
padding-bottom: -85px;}

footer {
background: #959595;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
color: #ffffff;
height: 85px;}
```

Comment: Check this tutorial out: http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

or this codepen: http://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

Comment: aren't you opening 3 div's that you don't close after '<!-- ASIDE NAV AND CONTENT -->'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems. The first is that your `header` and `section` take up more space than you have adjusted for in your `section`. Secondly, you should use `margin-bottom` instead of `padding-bottom` when you adjust for the footer height (negative padding isn't supported).

So what you need to do is to put the header and main section in a common wrapper element. That wrapper element is the one that should adjust for the footer height using the following "trick":

```
min-height: 100%; 
margin-bottom: -85px;
```

Something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header></header>
      <section></section>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

with this styling:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background: red;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -85px; 
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 85px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing it: https://jsfiddle.net/63fo4tq4/

Comment: This mostly works.. the sizing is all correct. Now I just need the white to fill the space between the last of the text and the footer, and not the rest of the to cover the background above the blue top border.

Comment: I actually don't understand what you want, but it sounds like a different issue than the one you described initially. If it is a separate problem and this helped you with your original problem, please mark as correct and create a new question for your new problem. If not, could you try to explain it a bit better?

Comment: http://fabricatorsunlimited.com/test/quartzcare.html

If you look at the page now, the white box where the content should be is only as long as the content is to fill it. I want to white box to go all the way down to the footer, covering the concrete background of the page. So everything from the 1px blue border should be white until you hit the gray footer.

Comment: Actually I think I just figured it out.. applied background image to header and not body.

Answer (score 0):

Im not pretty sure why your css is causing this, i managed to inspect you page and fount that your `<section>` element has the property `height:100%`.

I checked your css and that property seems to be commented, but the browsers loads it anyway.

Try to remove that property in your css.